# useNavigate not redirecting ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to make a post request and when the data has been sent I want the function to redirect me to the '/games' page where the games are being displayed from the SQL data base.

For some reason when I click on the button to execute the request the data is sent but is not redirecting. The data is added to the SQL data base.

I don't know what am I missing.

Here is my code

````
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Create.css'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios'

const Create = () => {
    
    // helps me to redirect to another page
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
    //To get the input text information
    const [game, setGame] = useState('');
    const [genre, setGenre] = useState('');
    const [year, setYear] = useState(0);
    const [platform, setPlatform] = useState('');

    const [showError, setShowError] = useState(false);

    const addGame = () => {

        //to show error messagge when there is not text content in the inputs
        if (!game || !genre || !year || !platform) {
            setShowError(true)
            return; // prevent the post request to be made
        }

        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/create',
            {
                game: game,
                genre: genre,
                year: year,
                platform: platform
            })
            .then((result) => {
                console.log('added succesfully')
                navigate("/games");
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('error mesagge' + err)
            });
    }

    return (
        <div className="create">
            <div className="create-container ">
                <h2 className="create-title headtext-h2">Add a Game</h2>
                <form className="create-form">
                    <label className='create-label headtext-label'>Game Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className='create-input ' onChange={(e) => {
                        setGame(e.target.value);
                    }} />
                    <label className='create-label headtext-label'>Genre</label>
                    <input type="text" className='create-input' onChange={(e) => {
                        setGenre(e.target.value);
                    }} />
                    <label className='create-label headtext-label'>Year</label>
                    <input type="number" className='create-input' onChange={(e) => {
                        setYear(e.target.value);
                    }} />
                    <label className='create-label headtext-label'>Platform</label>
                    <input type="text" className='create-input' onChange={(e) => {
                        setPlatform(e.target.value);
                    }} />
                    { showError && (
                        <div className="error">Please fill all the fields</div>
                    )}
                    <button type='button' className='create-button neon-button-form' onClick={()=>{addGame()}}>ADD</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Create;
```

This is my container that has the routers
```
import Home from './Home';
import Create from './Create';
import Games from './Games'


import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './Container.css'


const Container = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Router>
            <Link to={'/'} className='home-button neon-button-form'>Home</Link>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
                    <Route exact path="/create" element={<Create></Create>}></Route>
                    <Route exact path="/games" element={<Games></Games>}></Route>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Container;
```

Thank you so much for your help!!
````

Answer (score 0):

If it helps try

```
navigate("/games", { replace: true });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, I dont know what I have to do to make that happen

Comment: I noticed that if I put the navigate("/games"); outside the then(()) call back function it works, I dont know if that would be correct to do